# Using Keras APIs, how can I import images in batches with exactly K instances of each ID in a given batch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, file-import

I'm trying to implement batch hard triplet loss, as seen in Section 3.2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.06271.pdf.

I need to import my images so that **each batch has exactly K instances of each ID in a particular batch**. Therefore, **each batch must be a multiple of K**.

I have a directory of images too large to fit into memory and therefore I am using `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()` to import the images, but I can't see any parameters for this function to allow the functionality I need.

***How can I achieve this batch behaviour using Keras?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try merging several data streams together in a controlled manner.

Given you have K instances of `tf.data.Dataset` (does not matter how you instantiate them) that are responsible for supplying training instances of particular IDs, you can concatenate them to get even distribution inside a mini-batch:

```
ds1 = ...  # Training instances with ID == 1
ds2 = ...  # Training instances with ID == 2
...
dsK = ... # Training instances with ID == K



train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds1, ds2, ..., dsK)).flat_map(concat_datasets).batch(batch_size=N * K)
```

where the `concat_datasets` is the merge function:

```
def concat_datasets(*datasets):
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(datasets[0])
    for i in range(1, len(datasets)):
        ds = ds.concatenate(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(datasets[i]))
    return ds
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Tensorflow 2.4 I don't see a standard way of doing that with an `ImageDataGenerator`.

So I think you need to write your own based on the `tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence` class, so you are free to define the batch contents yourself.

References:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence
[https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly)