# How can I get a list of Tensorflow Dataset objects from a directory, each containing images from just one ID?

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras

In [Using Keras APIs, how can I import images in batches with exactly K instances of each ID in a given batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67055666/using-keras-apis-how-can-i-import-images-in-batches-with-exactly-k-instances-of), the answer from Dmytro Prylipko requires that I have a list of `tf.data.Dataset` objects to pass into `tf.data.Dataset.zip`.

I need each `tf.data.Dataset` object to only contain only instances of one ID, and for there to be an equal number of `tf.data.Dataset` objects as there are IDs.

My data consists of images imported from a directory using the following structure:

```
path/to/image_dir/
  split_name/  # Ex: 'train'
    label1/  # Ex: 'airplane' or '0015'
      xxx.png
      xxy.png
      xxz.png
    label2/
      xxx.png
      xxy.png
      xxz.png
  split_name/  # Ex: 'test'
    ...
```

**How can I get this list of `tf.data.Dataset` objects?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the answers in the following links, I have come up with an example to implement this requirement:

[TensorFlow: training on my own image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340129/tensorflow-training-on-my-own-image)

[Create tensorflow dataset from image local directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54590363/create-tensorflow-dataset-from-image-local-directory)

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices

Example implementation:

Given the following directory structure:

```
os.listdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training')

output: ['cats', 'dogs']

base_path = '/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training'

# Function to create list (image_list_final) of lists where each list will have the filenames of each class and
# another list (label_list_final) of lists where each list will have the labels of the class
 
def read_data():
  image_list_final = []
  label_list_final = []
  label_map_dict = {}
  count_label = 0
  for class_name in os.listdir(base_path):
    image_list = []
    label_list = []
    class_path = os.path.join(base_path, class_name)
    label_map_dict[class_name]=count_label
    for image_name in os.listdir(class_path):
      image_path = os.path.join(class_path, image_name)
      label_list.append(count_label)
      image_list.append(image_path)
    count_label += 1
    image_list_final.append(image_list)
    label_list_final.append(label_list)
  return image_list_final, label_list_final, label_map_dict

image_list_final, label_list_final, label_map_dict = read_data()

# create the datasets where the dataset_list will have one dataset for images in each class
dataset_list = []
for i,j in zip(image_list_final,label_list_final):
    dataset_list.append(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(i), tf.constant(j))))
    #dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(i))
    #dataset = dataset.repeat(epochs)
    #dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function).batch(batch_size)

# the below function to parse the filenames and labels in the dataset into arrays
def _parse_function(filename, label):
    image_string = tf.io.read_file(filename, "file_reader")
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image_decoded, tf.float32)
    return image, label

dataset = dataset_list[0].map(_parse_function)

#Check result
for i in dataset.take(1):
  print(i)
```

For a more detailed implementation example, please check the below link:
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/abhiatgith/ipynbees/blob/master/How%20Tos/Creating_TF_Datasets_by_Class_Labels_Dogs_vs_Cats.ipynb

Comment: Thank you - I see that you've commented out dataset.repeat(epochs), is it important to include this when creating datasets or can it be omitted?

Comment: It is not required to just create the dataset but these are methods(repeat, shuffle etc) that can be used on your dataset object as per your use case. You can take a look [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) for details on the methods that are available.